# with password validification javascript and html form

Tags: javascript, html

Im trying to code a simple task.
i need to get a password from html form, and check if there is both numbers and letters there, and that the password is not longer then 10 letters or short then 4.
so i wrote something (probably terrible) and its not working (surprisingly xD).
anyways, heres my code.

```
        function checkpassword(checked_id, error_id, err_color){

             var upperCaseLetters = /[A-Z]/g;
             var lowerCaseLetters = /[a-z]/g;
             var numbers = /[0-9]/g;
             element_checked = document.getElementById(checked_id);
             element_error = document.getElementById(error_id);
             element_error.style.color = err_color;
             if (!checked_id.value.match(upperCaseLetters) && !checked_id.value.match(lowerCaseLetters)) {
                 element_checked.style.backgroundColor = err_color;
                 element_error.innerHTML = "enter letters";
                 return false;
             }
             else if(!checked_id.value.match(numbers))
             {
                 element_checked.style.backgroundColor = err_color;
                 element_error.innerHTML = "Enter numbers";
                 return false;
             }
             return true;

       }
```

Comment: You should definitely use a lib, like [validator](https://github.com/validatorjs/validator.js). Do not reinvent the wheel.

Comment: im  not trying to xD, what is a lib? if you are talking about library, i cant use outside sources (like ready files or something.) i need to write it my self, and maybe to get some ideas

Answer (score 1):

The primary issue is that you used `checked_id.value`, which should be `element_checked.value`.

Also, generally it's advisable to create variables with `let` instead of `var` if you don't need them to be global.